# Update specific row in grid view visual studio ASP.NET

Tags: sql, visual-studio, gridview, sql-server-2012, aspxgridview

I have a problem when I try to update only one specific field in one row ,all of the rows get updated in that field I DONT want that to happen(all I want is that spacific row to get updated). Please help below is some images of my problem to help explain what im saying.

trying to update only the first row CHECKTYPE field - http://i59.tinypic.com/28cm24z.png

All of the rows get updated - http://i61.tinypic.com/30w2gt3.png

the update query im using - i57.tinypic.com/2poyw5k.png

Comment: You'll need to add a WHERE clause to identify which record you are trying to update. In your example the field CheckTime seems to be unique. So you'll need to add the clause "Where checktime = '<the time of the record you are trying to update>'"

Comment: How are you updating the grid view cell? Can you show that code?